# Get total sum of repeating IDs stored in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have a multidimensional array of items added to cart in codeigniter. Lets say I order food for me and several friends (specific IDs stored in next level array). Now in case someone has more items I need to get total sum of each friend and save it as money owned to me. How to loop all items to get total sum of each friend with same ID (I cannot move the friend ID to parent array). I store them to database in a way we can see in the table below in non-repeating way. I need a new array to get results like this(to store/update them).

| friend_id | amount_owned |
| --- | --- |
| 52 | 35 |
| 28 | 5 |
| friend_id 0 is me...we skip me != 0 |  |

```
Array
(
    [array] => Array
        (
    [carthashid1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [foodid] => 322
                            [price] => 5
                            [name] => Chicken Burger
                            [options] => Array
                                (
                                    [friend_id] => 52
                                    [special_instructions] => 
                                )
                            [rowid] => ceec8698316fe95ec9d7dccf961f32c1
                            [num_added] => 5
                            [sum_price] => 25
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [foodid] => 323
                            [price] => 5
                            [name] => Beef Burger
                            [options] => Array
                                (
                                    [friend_id] => 52
                                    [special_instructions] => 
                                )

                            [rowid] => c2d1c15d159123d1cbdce967785ef06e
                            [num_added] => 2
                            [sum_price] => 10
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [foodid] => 322
                            [price] => 5
                            [name] => Chicken Burger
                            [options] => Array
                                (
                                    [friend_id] => 28
                                    [special_instructions] => 
                                )
                            [rowid] => 3daa7b14b23a5c0afa9b196ea6e35227
                            [num_added] => 1
                            [sum_price] => 5
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [foodid] => 323
                            [price] => 5
                            [name] => Beef Burger
                            [options] => Array
                                (
                                    [friend_id] => 0
                                    [special_instructions] => 
                                )
                            [rowid] => 734c9cc82cf35e2dcc42f28d96a8ebde
                            [num_added] => 1
                            [sum_price] => 5
                        )

                )

        )
    [finalSum] => 45
    [finalItemsCount] => 9
)
```

Comment: Please use `var_export($your_array);` and post that instead of what you have, then we can use it easily when testing an answer

Comment: I didnt want to confuse it with other stuff in the code. I will be very satisfied with a direction or example code with a foreach loop i need to use. I was thinking it could be something simple...llike "foreach friend_id", sum up their amounts and create an array out of that :)

Comment: You showed us a `print_r()` but if you had shown a `var_export();` I could have copied and pasted from your question into my test :)

Comment: If I only knew how to do that xD I will know next time (researched it now)...but Violaa!!! I just saved my debtors to DB with your answer! thank you for quick and prompt answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have taken me less time to check my answer if I didnt have to Hand Code the array, but here it is anyway

```
$input = [
    'array' => [
        'carthashid1' => [
            [
                'foodid' => 322, 'price' => 5,
                'name' => 'Chicken Burger', 
                'options' => ['friend_id' => 52, 'special_instructions' => ''],
                'rowid' => 'ceec8698316fe95ec9d7dccf961f32c1', 'num_added' => 5,'sum_price' => 25
            ],
            [
                'foodid' => 322, 'price' => 5,
                'name' => 'Beef Burger',
                'options' => ['friend_id' => 52,'special_instructions' => ''],
                'rowid' => 'ceec8698316fe95ec9d7dccf961f32c1', 'num_added' => 2,'sum_price' => 10
            ],
            [
                'foodid' => 322,'price' => 5,'name' => 'Chicken Burger',
                'options' => ['friend_id' => 28,'special_instructions' => ''],
                'rowid' => 'ceec8698316fe95ec9d7dccf961f32c1', 'num_added' => 1,'sum_price' => 5
            ],
            [
                'foodid' => 322, 'price' => 5, 'name' => 'Beef Burger',
                'options' => ['friend_id' => 0,'special_instructions' => ''],
                'rowid' => 'ceec8698316fe95ec9d7dccf961f32c1', 'num_added' => 1, 'sum_price' => 5
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

$friends = [];
foreach($input['array']['carthashid1']  as $ordered){
    if ($ordered['options']['friend_id'] == 0) {
        // its me, ignore me
        continue;
    }
    if ( ! isset($friends[$ordered['options']['friend_id']]) ) {
        // initialise the accumulator for this friend
        $friends[$ordered['options']['friend_id']] = 0; 
    } 
    $friends[$ordered['options']['friend_id']] += $ordered['sum_price'];    
}

print_r($friends);
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [52] => 35
    [28] => 5
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could theoretically do entire task in single DB query, also the friend_id can be moved to parent array by modifying DB query.

Slightly different approach to keep `friend_id, amount_owned` structure:

```
$owned = [];
foreach($arr['array']['carthashid1'] as $item){
    if(isset($item['options']['friend_id']) && $item['options']['friend_id'] != 0)
    {
        if(count($owned) && ($key = array_search($item['options']['friend_id'], array_column($owned, 'friend_id'))) !== false){
            // we found friend id in array lets add the price:
            $owned[$key]['amount_owned'] += $item['sum_price'];
            continue;
        }
        // when we dont find the friend id in array create that item here:
        $owned[] = ['friend_id' => $item['options']['friend_id'], 'amount_owned' => $item['sum_price']];
    }
}

print_r($owned);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [friend_id] => 52
            [amount_owned] => 35
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [friend_id] => 28
            [amount_owned] => 5
        )
)
```